# getElementsBytagName does not work with DomDocument60

Tags: c++, xml, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

`getElementsByTagName()` works with DomDocument, but it does not work with `DomDocument60`.

In the below snippet, `getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t(".//author"), &xml2);` return a `NULL` pointer in xml2.

When i change from  DomDocument60 to DomDocument, only then it works.
i need to use DomDocument60 in my project.

Any idea how this issue can be fixed, if i use DomDocument60. 
Any help is appreciated.

Below is the snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#import "msxml6.dll" raw_interfaces_only  raw_native_types 
using namespace MSXML2;

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void LoadXML()
{
    HRESULT hr1, hr;
    hr1 = CoInitialize(NULL); 
    _variant_t vaNodeVal("c://Data.xml");

    VARIANT var1 = vaNodeVal;
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> sSourceInputXml = 0;
    hr = sSourceInputXml.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));

    if (hr == S_OK && sSourceInputXml != NULL)
    {
        VARIANT_BOOL isSuccessful = VARIANT_FALSE;

        hr = sSourceInputXml->load(var1, &isSuccessful);

        if( hr == S_OK && isSuccessful == VARIANT_TRUE )
        {

            CComQIPtr<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeList> xml2;
            sSourceInputXml->getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t(".//author"), &xml2); //xml2 returned over here is NULL 

            long lCount = 0;
            xml2->get_length(&lCount);
            bool isPresent = false;
            if (lCount == 0)
            {
                isPresent = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isPresent = true;
            }
        }
    }


    CoUninitialize();  
}
```

Data.xml used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this issue as well--it seems like getElementsByTagName is only looking at the direct children of the current node (e.g. on the document node, "catalog" would return one element, but "book" would return none). I'm not sure, but I believe this is because XSLPattern selection isn't supported in XML 6. If you want to stick with DOMDocument60, my best suggestion, while not the most efficient, is to recurse down the node tree while using getElementsByTagName to pick up everything that you're looking for.

Comment: This may have been a bug that has been fixed.  In any case I'm not seeing this issue with msxml6.dll 6.30.17763.55 here.